# Fixed and free shipping not working magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a weird problem that I do not know how to solve.

On tutorials and documentation is explained very simple. So the set-up for the Free Shipping and Fixed Shipping has been made. But on Front-End I keep getting an error like method_code and carrier_code for shipment are null by value.

Settings for Flat Rate Shipping:
[Flat Rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxZar.png)

Settings for Free Shipping:
[Free Shipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZBYC.png)

The error comes from default.js located in: app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default.js.

This error happens in console only on the /checkout/cart URL, but on the /checkout page not a single error.

The magento version is 2.2.0 from github Magento.

Any clue why this is happening?
The details about the store are already filled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when billing form is not fully filled. Just filled it completely then shipping methods will appear.